# Is there a term for 'The Secret Garden' and similar works?

Tags: genre, terminology

For some time now I've been curious about how to classify a small group of literary works. They include *The Secret Garden*, *Polyanna*, and to a lesser extent *Anne of Green Gables*. I'm sure there are others, but I haven't read them. While I personally am not planning on writing such a story, I feel that it would be useful to those who are, to know what to call their work. This will help in the publishing field.

While the events can differ quite a bit, these stories all seem to follow the same general idea: a young child (in these instances always a girl) is sent to live with people who are solitary, dark, brooding, unfriendly, etc. Throughout the story she brings some manner of light to their lives, as well as a changing cast of side characters. Below I've broken down each story to further show this common outline.

My question is this: Is there a term for these stories? Is this perhaps a sort of subgenre with an actual name? If you wanted to publish a story like these today, how would you pitch it?

You *could* say they are all coming of age stories, but I personally think that's a bit of a stretch. *Anne of Green Gables* certainly is a coming of age story, but the other two aren't. *The Secret Garden* does change the main character by the end, but that's not really a coming of age story (unless I misunderstand the genre definition). *Polyanna* changes only the people about the main character, and certainly isn't a coming of age story.

---

Breakdown of examples: Note that these are essentially very brief synopses, so do not read if you haven't read the books.

*The Secret Garden*

> *The Secret Garden* is about a young girl, Mary, who comes to live with her uncle (grandfather?) in England. Her uncle is always away, brooding over the death of his late wife, but Mary quickly discovers he has a son, bedridden and in a constant state of believing he will die. The boy does in fact just need sunlight and exercise, and Mary eventually convinces him to visit the secret garden she has discovered. Mary's uncle returns to his home to find his son cured, and light re-enters his life.

*Anne of Green Gables*

> In this tale, a young girl is adopted by an old couple. She was in fact adopted by accident, and at first the new parents try to send her back. She is there to stay however, and they soon come to love her. Probably more of coming of age story than the other two, but the basic pattern is still there.

*Polyanna*

> Probably the best example of the pattern, *Polyanna* is about a girl who comes to live with a lady (cannot remember how; it's been awhile since I read it). The lady, as well as plenty of side characters, are all stuck in their lives in some fasion, focusing inward on themselves, instead of seeing all the life about them. Throughout the book, Polyanna gets them all unstuck.

Comment: This one belongs on Literature SE.

Comment: When you perform a [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q="pollyanna"+"anne+of+green+gables"+"the+secret+garden") for all three titles – a lot comes up: an article on the "**female orphan archetype**" – which might be what you are looking for –  as well as other novels (*[Rebecca of Sunnybrook Farm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rebecca_of_Sunnybrook_Farm)* by Kate Douglas Wiggin or *[Little Women](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_Women)* by Louisa May Alcott).

Comment: @MarkBaker I looked at Literature SE first, and the 'genre' tag said specifically that questions asking for the genre of a work were off-topic. Since that is essentially what I'm doing, I figured it would be more on topic here.

Comment: Well, what's-the-word-for questions are on topic on English SE. Questions about existing literature are explicitly off topic here.

Comment: @MarkBaker Single word requests on English SE aren't for genres though. They're more for synonyms or single words to take the place of a lot of description. I suppose it might *technically* be on topic, but I kind of feel like it would go against the spirit of the tag...

Comment: I have edited my question to explain why I feel this question is on topic.

Comment: Are you asking for a term or are you asking about genre? Asking for a term is clearly off topic. (It is clearly on topic on English SE.) Asking about genre might be on topic is you could explain why you want to know and how it would impact your writing decisions.

Comment: At the end of the day you're not asking a question about the act of writing professionally. To re-open this I'd want it to be on topic for the professional writing world. Hint: "If I were to write this type of story, what genre should I pitch it as/sell it as to attract the correct publisher/readership?" or "If I were to publish this type of book, what classification would bring me the most readers?" This is different enough, imo, because it may not line up with literary classification, which might not actually be useful to a writer as that's usually a post-mortem endeavor.

Comment: @Kirk I can work with that. I've edited the question to more follow that line of thought. Let me know if you think it's worthy of a re-open, or if you think I need to edit it more.

Comment: @ThomasMyron to get my reopen vote it would need to say something along the lines of, how would you pitch a story like Anne of Green Gables today? For a working writer, genre is about marketing.

Comment: @Mark Baker I've edited the third paragraph to say essentially that.

Comment: Sorry, Thomas Myron, and you seem to be barking up a tree that hasn't yet grown.